# Adobe Edge onload event

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

I have an HTML file created in Adobe Edge 5.1. I need to execute a javascript function after stage is initialized and displayed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Totally possible. You can tell if a composition is loaded by using the adobe edge bootstrap callback function.

```
AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback
```

Use it like this:

```
AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback(function (compId) {
    console.log('composition loaded: ' + compId);    
});
```

I have more documentation on my [site](http://iwearshorts.com/blog/adobe-edge-animate-events/), but if you want to know when the timeline is done as well you could do:

```
AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback(function (compId) {
            console.log('composition loaded: ' + compId);    
            AdobeEdge.Symbol.bindTimelineAction(compId, "stage", "Default Timeline", "complete", function(sym, e) {
                console.log('timeline complete');
            });
        });
```

From the [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/edgeanimate/api/current/index.html), it looks like the function is called

> when an Edge composition is loaded and ready to play

Here's an example embedded on a site:

```
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="edge/specialized/edge_includes/edge.5.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .edgeLoad-EDGE-150750921 { visibility:hidden; }
    </style>
    <script>
       AdobeEdge.loadComposition('edge/specialized/specialized', 'EDGE-150750921', {
            scaleToFit: "none",
            centerStage: "horizontal",
            minW: "0",
            maxW: "undefined",
            width: "550px",
            height: "309px"
        }, {dom: [ ]}, {dom: [ ]});

        AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback(function (compId) {
            console.log('composition loaded: ' + compId);    
            AdobeEdge.getComposition(compId).load("edge/specialized/specialized_edgeActions.js");

            // do some other stuff on the page
        });
    </script>
    <!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible and use, composition ready event.

Comment: thanks for answer and for contributing to the stack!  Can you provide a little more detail though (links,  code snippets,  explanation,  etc.)?

Comment: I added some more documentation below

Answer (score 0):

look for the "Stage" element in the "Elements" panel.

click on the curly braces {} to the left of that element listing.  that will take you to the event handlers.

click on the plus (+) button to add a "compositionReady" event handler.

then enter whatever code what you want in the text editor that appears.